# How much damage is dealt per Newton of force?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How exactly does Force translate to Damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54677/how-exactly-does-force-translate-to-damage)

Consider a shielded or armored enemy that will not be thrown, lifted, or otherwise significantly moved by a biotic power. If it is struck by a biotic power (like Throw or Shockwave), how much damage will be dealt to it per Newton of force?

This is irrelevant to any damage caused by collision with various surfaces.

Comment: Just a wild guess here - but since most biotic powers have both Force and Damage properties, I would imagine they behave more or less independently, with Force being responsible for how likely they are to be thrown around. Not physically accurate, obviously, but otherwise why separate them out? Being thrown against a wall (from upgraded Force) could cause secondary impact damage, though. Again, just a guess - am interested to read proper answers :D

Comment: I actually made this question after seeing that one. Originally, I wanted to post a comment on one of the answers to that question to try fishing my intended answer out of it but my reputation isn't high enough to do so. So, the best thing I could do is post a permutation of the question. I am seeking a more precise answer than the question you brought up, though.

Comment: Also, neither Throw nor Pull have a damage value, but still do damage on contact.

Comment: @ChristopherReeves good point. So much for my guess :)

Comment: It's pretty r*****ed that this was closed and merged. The question that this was agreed to be an exact duplicate of does not contain the answer to this question. Even the question itself doesn't fish for the answer this one does.

Since I can't post comments, the only way for me to get this answer from this site is to re-post this question. Clearly, I'm not supposed to do that. How am I going to find the answer I'm looking for?

Comment: @ChristopherReeves For what it's worth, I was fishing for *exactly* the answer that this one does, and I'm actually rather disappointed that I never got it. But the fact that my question wasn't answers satisfactorily (and it wasn't), doesn't make this less of a duplicate. Though I will toss a bounty on my original question to try to stir up some fresh activity.